# Tradeoffs in increasing $MAXSTACKSIZE in delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm facing an issue when maintaining legacy code. I'm trying to increase the size of a static array of AnsiChar in a piece of legacy code to cover a new use case.
The new size is supposed to be 1 million.
I'm now getting stack overflow exceptions.
My findings show that i'm actually hitting MAXSTACKSIZE ( https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Memory_allocation_sizes_(Delphi) ) for the thread which is just above 1MB. It all makes sense.

I'm now contemplating increasing the stack size and wonder what are the tradeoffs or dangers in doing so.

I'd like to avoid re-writing the code logic to avoid introducing regression in pre-existing critical use cases, which is why i'm looking at increasing stack size instead of refactoring code. Pure risk management.

Thank you.

Comment: How is declared the array? Is it a local variable?

Comment: Infinite recursion is more likely to be the problem than large objects getting passed by value on the stack. Can check the call stack for repeated call blocks (call to A, then B then C repeating) or increase the stack and see if it still crashes but takes longer to do so.

Comment: @Brian If you push 1MB onto the stack, you do get an overflow (when using the default size).

Comment: @Olivier Yes it's a local variable. 

myarray    : Array[0..1000000] of AnsiChar ;

Comment: Then either increase the stack size (there is no drawback associated with that) or use a dynamic array instead (dynamic arrays are allocated on the heap).

Comment: That's a fairly scary local variable.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I agree :)
But it's also a legacy piece of critical code that i'd rather not risk changing if i can avoid it.

Comment: I would recomend to use a full debug [FastMM](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4) build to Check your Programm in debug Mode... Best of luck if you have for i : integer to Lengt(Array) Source...

Answer (score 1):

As proposed here : [Tradeoffs in increasing $MAXSTACKSIZE in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996527/tradeoffs-in-increasing-maxstacksize-in-delphi?noredirect=1#comment121944669_68996527)

I ended setting MAXSTACKSIZE to 2000000 (2 million bytes).
I haven't noticed any anomaly so far. I'm closing this issue. Will reopen if i see anything related.